# Convert data.frame to zoo

Tags: r, statistics, zoo

I want to convert a `data.frame` to a zoo object. My `df` looks like that:

```
> (str(StockPriceReturns))
'data.frame':   3036 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Date        : Factor w/ 3036 levels "01.01.2002","01.01.2003",..: 1 102 202 301 600 701 802 902 1001 1300 ...
 $ TotalReturns: num  183 183 186 191 191 ...
NULL
```

What I tried:

*directly:*

Here I am getting an error...

```
> (z1 <- read.zoo(StockPriceReturns, drop=FALSE))
Error in read.zoo(StockPriceReturns, drop = FALSE) : 
  index has 3036 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 ...
```

*function:*

I am getting an error too ;(

```
    dfToZoo <- function(df) {
        require(zoo)
        date <- as.Date(df[, 1], format = '%d.%m.%y')
        with(df, zoo(date,freq))
    } 

> (z1 <- dfToZoo(StockPriceReturns))
Error in MATCH(order.by, order.by) : object 'freq' not found
```

My question is what is a better way to convert a `data.frame` to a zoo object? How to properly do that?

I appreciate your reply

Comment: `StockPriceReturns` does not have a column named `freq`.  Also, your `zoo` call is backwards -- should be `zoo(TotalReturns, date)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding the attempt to use `read.zoo`, the format of the first column must be specified as it differs from the default.  See `?read.zoo` for proper use of that function. Also there is a vignette `vignette("zoo-read")` entirely devoted to `read.zoo` examples.

```
DF <- data.frame(Date = c("01.01.2002","01.01.2003"), TotalReturns = c(183, 183))
library(zoo)
read.zoo(DF, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
## 2002-01-01 2003-01-01 
##        183        183
```

The function `dfToZoo` provided in the question uses `zoo` incorrectly (see `?zoo` to understand the arguments) and the value of the `format` argument should be `"%d.%m.%Y"` with an upper case Y.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Why is the formating of `"%d.%m.%Y"` with a large `"...%Y"`?

Answer (score 1):

A quick take on a dfTozoo function.  It gives you the flexibility of specifying the date format if different from the included default:

```
dfTozoo = function(tsdataframe, dateformat="%m/%d/%Y"){

  library(zoo)

  framedates = as.Date(tsdataframe[,1], format=dateformat)
  n=ncol(tsdataframe)
  zoodata = zoo(tsdataframe[,2:n], order.by=framedates)

  return(zoodata)
}
```